# Ubuntu 18.04 networking

Tags: networking

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 but unable to get network working. 
I am still used to ifconfig. Now have no network and have to use 'ip'

- Wired network, setting DHCP: DHCP server is present dmesg shows that link is detected, but no IP address.
- running sudo dhclient hangs
- Configuring an ip address manually also does not work: unable to ping the router.
- The "old" ifconfig shows statistics counters (rcvd/transmitted) where is this with ip ?

Normally never have problems troubleshouting network issues, but this new Ubuntu is getting frustrated. After install it destroyed my dual boot, now after a few hours unable to get network operational.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager)` will show you log data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure NetworkManager is installed? It should make most common network setups work out of the box. If it is, you can try `nm-connection-editor` to edit any specific data for your connection. Also look up the information `nmcli` gives you, especially `nmcli general status` or `nmcli device <ethernet device name>`. Come back here with any additional insight or information...